# How to select values with a condition on multiple columns and multiple rows in pandas (best practice)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select (unique) values from one column in a pandas data frame based on conditions on multiple columns **and** multiple rows. Consider the following example data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Developer': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                   'Language': ['Java', 'Python', 'Python', 'Java', 'Python', 'Python', 'Java', 'Python', 'C++'],
                   'Skill_Level': [1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3],
                   'Version': ["x.x", "2.x", "3.x", "x.x", "2.x", "3.x", "x.x", "3.x", "x.x"]
                   })
```

```
    Developer    Language    Skill_Level    Version
0           A        Java              1        x.x
1           A      Python              3        2.x
2           A      Python              3        3.x
3           B        Java              3        x.x
4           B      Python              2        2.x
5           B      Python              3        3.x
6           C        Java              3        x.x
7           C      Python              1        3.x
8           C         C++              3        x.x
```

Now I want to find all developers who know Java with a skill level of at least 3 **and** also know Python (no matter the version) with a skill level of at least 2.

The way I solved it for now was by selecting one set based on the Java condition, another set based on the Python condition and then doing an inner merge to get the set of developers matching all conditions:

```
result_java_df = df[(df["Language"] == "Java") & (df["Skill_Level"] >= 3)][["Developer"]]
result_python_df = df[(df["Language"] == "Python") & (df["Skill_Level"] >= 2)][["Developer"]]
result_df = result_java_df.merge(result_python_df, on="Developer")
result_df = result_df.drop_duplicates()
```

```
    Developer
0   B
```

Is there a more "elegant" way to do this? I feel like I am overlooking smth. Especially if I want to select based on more row-based conditions (e.g. selecting developers who know 4 languages at certain skill levels) this will become quite convoluted, and of course justify writing a function to handle such selections. Hence I am wondering if pandas supports this somehow and I just didn't find that feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I ran

```
    qualified=    df.groupby("Developer").apply(
        lambda x: 
            any(
                    (x.Language == "Java") & 
                    (x.Skill_Level >=3)
                ) & 
            any(
                    (x.Language == "Python") & 
                    (x.Skill_Level >= 2))
        )
```

I got

```
Developer
A    False
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool
```

You can then subset with various methods, such as

```
[developer for developer,status in qualified.items() if status]
```

(returns a list)

or

```
qualified[qualified]
```

(returns a Series)

If you want to make it more general, you could do something like:

```
minimum_skill_levels = {"Java":3,
                    "Python":2}

qualified=    df.groupby("Developer").apply(
        lambda x: 
            all([any(
                    (x.Language == Language)&
                    (x.Skill_Level >= Skill_Level)
                    )
                 for Language, Skill_Level in minimum_skill_levels.items()
                 ])
        )
```

Comment: I like this approach, it seems to generalize well, it's easy to add more conditions, and it is pretty clear which conditions are applied to the selection. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got something working thanks to pandas multiindexing but it aint pretty, on the plus side, no loops, no lambdas. I think it's best practice because it uses slicing and indexing and once the data is properly formatted (proper index and columns), the performance should also be better.

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.IndexSlice


df_p = df.pivot_table(index = 'Language', columns = 'Developer')

java = df_p.loc['Java'] >= 3

python = df_p.loc['Python'] >= 2

df_p.loc[:, idx[:, java & python]]
```

outputs the proper Developer, as a column

```
df_p.loc[:, idx[:, java & python]]['Skill_Level'].columns.tolist()
```

gives the category(ies) in a list if you need them later.

Comment: This works in this particular case, but seems to be that it does not generalize well. How would you deal with this approach if you have additional conditions like age has to be between 20 and 40, has to be located in Europe, etc.!?

Comment: You can chain arbitrary conditions as you'd like, have you read the documentation on index slicing.